# could not fetch info from comment table

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Facebook just notified me about "July 2013 Breaking Changes". There is one related to my app.

**Deprecating 'comments' field from 'stream' FQL table** 
We are deprecating the 'comments' field from 'stream' FQL table. Please select the 'comment_info' column to fetch the 'can_comment' and 'comment_count' fields (formerly called 'can_post' and 'count'), and use the comment table directly to retrieve the list of comments.

In our app we are using query like this :

```
SELECT post_id, message, likes.count, comments.count, comments.comment_list FROM stream   
WHERE source_id=me() AND actor_id=me() LIMIT 500
```

and receive response like this :

```
{
"data": [
{
**"post_id": "100002510712421_451594341600919",** 
  "message": "text", 
  "likes": {
    "count": 1
  }, 
  "comments": {
    "count": 2, 
    "comment_list": [
      {
        "fromid": 100001228089363, 
        "time": 1367073822, 
        "text": "text", 
        "text_tags": [
        ], 
        "id": "100002510712421_451594341600919_1181882", 
        "likes": 0, 
        "user_likes": false, 
        "post_fbid": 452073094886377
      }, 
      {
        "fromid": 100000020227797, 
        "time": 1367173047, 
        "text": "text", 
        "text_tags": [
        ], 
        "id": "100002510712421_451594341600919_1183852", 
        "likes": 0, 
        "user_likes": false, 
        "post_fbid": 452790081481345
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

....

ok now try to fetch info from 'comment' table using given post_id

```
SELECT id, text, time, fromid FROM comment WHERE 
post_id='100002510712421_451594341600919'

{
"data": [
]
}
```

The response is empty 
Can anybody come up with solution? We really need it!

Answer (score 0):

your query looks just fine, are you sure that this post_id exists and you have permission to read it?

```
SELECT id, text, time, fromid FROM comment WHERE 
post_id='125909647492772_502974003098530'

returns

{
    "data": [
    {
      "id": "502974003098530_78616446", 
      "text": "saugeil!", 
      "time": 1364309881, 
      "fromid": 526559276
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yep, I am sure. You can see that I could fetch it using old query style with the same access token.

Comment: the problem seems definitly related to the postid, I just tried another postid from your wall 100002510712421_202158336544522 and get results.  was that postid public or restricted to your friends?

Answer (score 0):

I'veI run into the same issue.

Surprisingly, I was able to fix it by using only last part of the post_id, i.e.: '451594341600919' instead of '100002510712421_451594341600919'. But it works only sometimes and in your case doesn't work at all.